# trying to understand some codes which is related to variable declaration in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function sayAlice() {
  var sayAlert = function() { console.log(alice); }
  var alice = 'Hello Alice';
  return sayAlert;
}
sayAlice()();
</script>
```

In console, it shows `Hello Alice`

Question:

`var alice`(variable declaration) is after  `var sayAlert`, why it still shows the right result, not something like 'undefined'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because at the time that `sayAlert` is actually executed (in the `sayAlice()()` call), `Hello Alice` has been assigned to `alice`.  Because of closures in JavaScript, `alice` is available to `sayAlert` at execution time.

Answer (score 2):

It's the JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting mechanism.
Look at [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html). Due to hoisting, javascript interprets your script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
   function sayAlice() {
      var alice;
      var sayAlert = function() { console.log(alice); }
      alice = 'Hello Alice';
      return sayAlert;
    }
    sayAlice()();
</script>
```

The `var alice;` is **hoisted** to before the declaration of `var sayAlert = function() { console.log(alice); }`.

Comment: No. It doesn't have to do with hoisting. It has to do with the fact the the inner function is executed *after* the variable assignment. (Hoisting only explains why the placement of `var` doesn't matter to variable *scoping*; not why this code outputs the correct behavior - in particular the assignment is *not moved*.)

Comment: @KhanhTO at that point `alice` is first looked up locally and then globally (through `window`) and doesn't exist in either.  It would be undefined. `sayAlert` isn't executed until after `sayAlice` has returned, that is why *sayAlice* has double-parens (to execute *sayAlice* and then *sayAlert*).  `alice` is populated at that point because it is still in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Because `saysAlert` is a function and
it is only implemented when you return `saysAlert` which house the `function` and after the fact that you declared `alice`.

This one will give you an undefined variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function sayAlice() {
var sayAlert='';
console.log(alice); // alice is undefine up to this line
var alice = 'Hello Alice';
return sayAlert;
}
sayAlice()();
</script>
```

Your **original code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function sayAlice() {
  var sayAlert = function() { console.log(alice); } // function sayAlert is not yet implemented
  var alice = 'Hello Alice';
  return sayAlert; // function alert is implemented after the alice variable is define
 }
 sayAlice()();
 </script>
```

Comment: Because js doesnt compile procedurally

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
1:    function sayAlice() {
2:       var sayAlert = function() { console.log(alice); }
3:       var alice = 'Hello Alice';
4:       return sayAlert;
5:    }
6:    sayAlice()();
</script>
```

- Line 2 is defining a function `sayAlert`, but not calling/executing it.  If you put `()` after the closing brace (`}`), then the log would print `undefined` because, as you mentioned, `alice` isn't defined until after.
- Line 4 just returns the `sayAlert` function, but again does not yet call it (notice it still doesn't have the `()`)
- Line 6 receives the function previously returned from the `sayAlice()` call and adds `()` to call the returned function (*sayAlert*).  So after Line 6 runs `sayAlice`, it effectively looks like `sayAlert()`, when it does that is when `console.log(...)` is called.  `alice` is still exposed and in scope as it has not yet been destroyed by the garbage collector (similarly how closures) work.